# jquery datepicker enlarge textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

[Cant embed pictures, but this picture shows my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly4pl.png)

im trying to change the size of the textarea which handles the date of the jquery datepicker. however i cant seem to find where i should do that.
after everything ive tried ive cleared the cache of my browser, and ive also used different browsers. all of them cut of the date halfway.

this is the code ive found in my files about the datepicker:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
defaultDate: +7,
autoSize: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
}); 

.datepicker { width: 56px!important; }
.ui-datepicker { width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; border: 1px solid #d5d5d5; background: #fafafa; margin-top: 1px; z-index: 3; display: none; }
.ui-datepicker-append { margin-left: 10px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header { position:relative; padding:.2em 0; border: 1px solid #E7E7E7; background: url(../images/leftNavBg.png) repeat-x; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next { position:absolute; top: 2px; width: 1.8em; height: 1.8em; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover { top: 1px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev { left:2px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next { right:2px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover { left:1px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover { right:1px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span, .ui-datepicker 
.ui-datepicker-next span { display: block; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -8px; top: 50%; margin-top: -8px;  }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title { margin: 0 2.3em; line-height: 1.8em; text-align: center; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select { font-size:1em; margin:1px 0; }
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month-year {width: 100%;}
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month, 
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year { width: 49%;}
.ui-datepicker table {width: 100%; font-size: .9em; border-collapse: collapse; margin:0 0 .4em; }
.ui-datepicker table .ui-state-default { border: 1px solid #d5d5d5; }
.ui-datepicker table tbody { font-size: 11px; }
.ui-datepicker th { padding: .7em .3em; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; border: 0;  }
.ui-datepicker td { border: 0; padding: 1px; }
.ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a { display: block; padding: .2em; text-align: right; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane { background-image: none; margin: .7em 0 0 0; padding:0 .2em; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; border-bottom: 0; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button { float: right; margin: .5em .2em .4em; cursor: pointer; padding: .2em .6em .3em .6em; width:auto; overflow:visible; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current { float:left; }
```

this is how i use it:

```
<input type='text' class='datepicker' class='topDir' title='Markera om leadet får finnas i NIXdatabasen' name='createdhigh' id='createdhigh' value='' tabindex='15' style='width: 200px;'/>
```

ive tried setting autosize to false, but nothing happens. ive also tried setting the values of these 2 lines higher with no success:

```
.datepicker { width: 56px!important; }
.ui-datepicker { width: 17em;
```

could anyone help me enlarge the textarea?

Comment: .datepicker { width: 56px!important; }......Change Here

Answer (score 0):

Using inline style or css should be enough, in your input tag you are usign class= twice, you should merge them into a single class attribute:

```
<input type='text' class='datepicker topDir' title='Markera om leadet får finnas i NIXdatabasen' name='createdhigh' id='createdhigh' value='' tabindex='15' style='width: 200px;'/>
```

Alsp check that your "topDir" doesn't have a width set as "!important" or that there is enough space in the page to contain bigger inputs.